# how to integrate two projects in spring mvc(1 war and 1 jar)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

Two Spring mvc web application for a project where one as internet and one as intranet. Both using few common packages and classes. I want to separate the intranet part and take it as a jar file then deploy it with internet war file. idea is to use the jar file in multiple similar projects where intranet part can be reused. Please suggest how to proceed with this approach.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create lib project which will have jar packaging, and both internet and intranet app will reuse code located in this project.

The pom.xml will looks following

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.domain.foobar</groupId>
  <artifactId>foobar-lib</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

</project>
```

then generate internet portlet (with war packaging) for example

mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.domain.foobar -DartifactId=foobar-internet -DarchetypeArtifactId=com.liferay.maven.archetypes:liferay-portlet-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=6.2.10.15

and to pom.xml of internet project add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.domain.foobar</groupId>
    <artifactId>foobar-lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

do the same for intranet portlet

mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.domain.foobar -DartifactId=foobar-intranet -DarchetypeArtifactId=com.liferay.maven.archetypes:liferay-portlet-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=6.2.10.15

and to pom.xml of internet project add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.domain.foobar</groupId>
    <artifactId>foobar-lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now both internet and intranet (war packaging) project sees code in lib (jar packaging) project.

So the architecture is

- Internet portlet (Spring MVC code goes here), WAR packaging
- Intranet portlet (Spring MVC code goes here), WAR packaging
- shared library (core code goes here), JAR packaging

I hope that I helped you becase your question wan't clear enough.